# Cassandra bootstrap and node repair

Tags: cassandra

Say I have to to a full Cassandra node restore by deleting all the files and restarting Cassandra. I see that some of the data gets restored to this node from the other nodes after it fully comes up. Then I have to do a nodetool repair to get the rest of the data. Is there a reason for this? Why didn't all the data get restored during the bootstrap? Also, is there a simply way to confirm that afterwards this restored node got all the data it had before including replicas?

Comment: How much data was copied by the bootstrap? And how much was added by repair? Did you run 'nodetool removenode' before bringing the node back up?

Comment: Most of the data was copied by the bootstrap. There were no transactions in the cluster at the time. We did not do removenode. Were we supposed to? If we removenode will this cause any other rebalancing in the cluster until we add this node back in?

Comment: You need to do removenode, otherwise Cassandra won't replicate the data the old node use to have. You can do it before or after adding the new node. It will cause the data that was on that node to be replicated to the other nodes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "It will cause the data that was on that node to be replicated to the other nodes". This node was corrupted so there is no longer any good data on it per se. So we remove whatever datafiles are still left there and restart it again. What will removenode do in this case?

Comment: If a node fails and loses the data on it, you want to create an additional copy of the data so that further failures don't cause data loss. This is what nodetool removenode does - it copies data from the remaining replicas to make another replica to ensure you have enough copies of your data.

Comment: My scenario is that I replace the node immediately after it fails. Basically delete all the data and immediately restart the node. So I don't really want replicas to go to other nodes. I just want the failed node to get the data it had before. So, in this case do I still need to do removenode?

Comment: Either you delete all the data *apart* from the system keyspace, restart and run repair. Or you delete all the data, bootstrap and run removenode. You can choose tokens one greater than the old node's tokens to minimize the removenode work if you want.

Comment: Assuming deleting everything inlcuding system, what is the exact sequence of steps? Is the removenode done before or after the bootstrap? Do I run this from a healthy node and remove the node about to be replaced? If I don't specify the tokens and I let Cassandra pick them, what is the amount of work that I won't be able to minimize?